# How can I use generics to extract all values of a particular type?

Tags: haskell, generic-programming

I have a data type like this:

```
data MyType = Foo Bool
            | Bar
            | Baz Bool (Maybe String) Bool
            | Quux Int String
```

Can I use generics to write a function `getBools :: MyType -> [Bool]` that returns a list of all the boolean fields in the input?

I came up with this type signature:

```
getAllOfType ::
  (Generic inner, Generic outer, HasDatatypeInfo inner, All2 HasDatatypeInfo (Code outer)) =>
  Proxy inner -> outer -> [inner]
```

Using `generics-sop`, but I don't think that's right. Comparing the `DatatypeInfo`s is not going to convince the type checker that the two types are equivalent.

Comment: If you own `MyType` then you can write `MyType' a = Foo a | ...`, replacing `Bool` with `a` everywhere and `type MyType = MyType' Bool`. Then you can derive `Foldable` (with the `DeriveFoldable` extension) and `toList` will give you a list of all of the `Bool`s in your structure. No generics required.

Comment: That's interesting, but doesn't really work for me. In reality, I want to extract different fields depending on use case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [uniplate](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/uniplate):

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

module M where

import Data.Data
import Data.Generics.Uniplate.Data

data MyType
  = Foo Bool
  | Bar
  | Baz Bool (Maybe String) Bool
  | Quux Int String
  deriving Data

getBools :: MyType -> [Bool]
getBools = universeBi
```